# не запускает приложение через другой exe'шник

Tags: c#, winforms, exe

Возникла такая проблема. Есть приложение, которое при обычном запуске работает как положено. Но когда я его пытаюсь запустить через другое приложение (к примеру через Process.Start), приложение открывается некорректно. В моем случае при запуске идет подключение к базе данных. При обычном запуске - подключение успешно, при запуске через другое приложение - подключение отсутствует. Почему, не понятно. 
Буду благодарен за любые идеи, почему так может быть.

Метод подключение к БД

```
private void ConnectionToBD()
        {
            try
            {
                cs = new ConnectionString();
                var loadData = cs.LoadFile("DataConnection.xml");
                string connString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User Id={2};Password={3}", loadData.Host, loadData.Database, loadData.UserId, loadData.PWD);
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Подключение отсутствует!");
            }

        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Измените catch { MessageBox.Show("Подключение отсутствует!"); }, на catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); } и у Вас будет больше информации, так как из Вашего вопроса непонятно какое исключение выбрасывается.

Comment: @XelaNimed добавил скрин ексепшина, только не понятно откуда берется постгре если работаю с SQL

Comment: При запуске из другого exe, текущая директория не меняется, видимо файл "DataConnection.xml" другой читается. Попробуйте полный путь.

Comment: @МаксимsaysReinstateMonica я прописую полный путь к exe

Comment: К `DataConnection.xml`

Comment: @МаксимsaysReinstateMonica не помогло, та же ошибка

Comment: Ну явно не тот файл читается. Подсмотрите значения `MessageBox.Show(loadData.Host);`, `MessageBox.Show(loadData.Database);`, и все станет ясно.

Comment: Попробуйте установить рабочую директорию, пример здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/114937/451518

Comment: @МаксимsaysReinstateMonica действительно, затягивает файл с директории текущего приложения, с которого я пытаюсь запустить  свое главное приложение. Как мне указать чтобы считывало файл с главного приложения? В методе изменил на `var loadData = cs.LoadFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\DataConnection.xml");` но проблему не исправило

Comment: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() у дочернего приложения = родительскому. Как написали выше, либо переназначить текущую директорию, либо полный путь к конфигу.

Comment: вообщем получилось исправить таким макаром `var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\Projects\Doc\FirstApp\bin\Release";
            startInfo.FileName = @"Message.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "DataConnection.xml";
            Process.Start(startInfo);` это можно было бы как-то сократить?

Comment: @erleug попробуйте `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`. Может в вашем случае это поможет

Comment: @pavl_o не, не помогает, ошибка остается